# How to get shimmer effect like facebook in flutter?

Tags: flutter, effect, shimmer

I am trying to create a video streaming app and want shimmer effect like facebook, any suggestion how to get it?

Comment: I have just written a detailed blog post on how to create a shimmer effect like that.
[check it out.](https://yassinebenkhay.com/how-to-create-a-shimmer-loading-effect-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shimmer 1.0.1 on https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer, a package provides an easy way to add shimmer effect in Flutter project

[image]

```
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';

SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 100.0,
  child: Shimmer.fromColors(
    baseColor: Colors.red,
    highlightColor: Colors.yellow,
    child: Text(
      'Shimmer',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40.0,
        fontWeight:
        FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```